# How do I display two strings in one TableRow?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, string

I have two values in my source code (currentHour and currentMinute from the TimePicker buttons) and I'd like to combine them together into a single string I can display in an xml layout (12:30 instead of 12 and 30)  I've been able to compile the code below but I'm getting stuck, its force closing and I need some help: all I want to do is add a little bit of code to combine the currentHour and currentMinute into one string so I can call the time from the TimePicker in an xml layout later.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

    private long rowID; 
    private EditText nameEt;
    private EditText capEt;
    private EditText codeEt;
    private TimePicker timeEt;
    private TimePicker minEt;
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

        nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
        capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
        codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
        timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
        //   minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.minEdit);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

        if (extras != null)
        {
            rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
            nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
            capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
            codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));
            timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) ? extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) : 0);
            minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
        }

        Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                        {
                            saveContact();
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                }

                else
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                }
            } 
        });
    }


    private void saveContact() 
    {
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
        {
            dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
        }
        else
        {
            dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                          nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),/* Storing as String*/
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Database Connector (.java)**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



public class DatabaseConnector {

    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException 
    {
        //open database in reading/writing mode
        database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } 

    public void close() 
    {
        if (database != null)
            database.close();
    }      

    public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time, String min) 
    {
        ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
        newCon.put("name", name);
        newCon.put("cap", cap);
        newCon.put("time", time);
        newCon.put("min", min);
        newCon.put("code", code);
        newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
        newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);

        open();
        database.insert("country", null, newCon);
        close();
    }


    public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code, String time, String min) 
    {
        ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
        editCon.put("name", name);
        editCon.put("cap", cap);
        editCon.put("time", time);
        editCon.put("min", min);
        editCon.put("code", code);
        editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
        editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);
        open();
        database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
        close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllContacts() 
    {
        return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                     null, null, null, null, "name");
    }

    public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
    {
        return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void deleteContact(long id) 
    {
        open(); 
        database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
        close();
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
03-24 00:48:57.779: D/Activity(6809): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-24 00:48:57.959: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6809): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-24 00:48:57.959: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca41000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:54
03-24 00:48:58.049: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dc22000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:75
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dcb8000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:78
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d4ce000 size:614400
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d6f7000 size:614400
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c929000 size:614400
03-24 00:49:10.623: W/dalvikvm(6809): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410889d8)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.saveContact(AddEditCountry.java:101)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.access$1(AddEditCountry.java:92)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry$1$1.doInBackground(AddEditCountry.java:65)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     ... 5 more
03-24 00:49:10.663: D/Activity(6809): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-24 00:49:10.693: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6809): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-24 00:49:10.693: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d4cb000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:57
03-24 00:49:10.713: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d8f7000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:68
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5e14e000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:72
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca41000 size:614400
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dc22000 size:614400
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dcb8000 size:614400
```

Comment: Something like `myHourVariable + ":" + myMinuteVariable"` ?

Comment: Can you check updated attempt # 2 and let me know if that looks crrent to you? (I'm trying to combine the currentHour and currentMinute from TimePicker into one string)

Comment: It's crashing... (force close)

Comment: how about pasting the stack trace from logcat?

Comment: I updated my logcat (as well as my source code with exactly where I'm at right now - I really appreciate the help with this - I've been stuck on this issue for 3 days now and its driving me insane)

Comment: On line 101 in AddEditCountry you try to access a null object. What code is there?